# How Do I Trap Error Code from git ls-remote?

Tags: git, bash, error-handling, error-code

Occasionally, my "git ls-remote" statement is returning a 401 Unauthorized status over HTTP, but not always. How do I trap this error status in Bash so that I don't proceed in my Bash script if I get an HTTP 401 status?

I was doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
GSERVER_STATUS=$(git ls-remote http://$GREMOTE/$GGROUP/$GREPO.git master | cut -f 1)
# rest of script goes here
```

About 50% of the time, it works. The other 50%, I'm getting:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing http://USER:PASS@SERVER/GROUP/REPO.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

(Of course, I changed the line above to keep my login credentials anonymous.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redirect it to a file, such as `/tmp/TSTRET` via `2>/tmp/TSTRET` and then test to see if that file is empty, or `cat` the file and test the result to see if it is NULL:

```
#!/bin/bash
GSERVER_STATUS=$(git ls-remote http://$GREMOTE/$GGROUP/$GREPO.git master 2>/tmp/TESTRET | cut -f 1)

if [[ -n `cat /tmp/TESTRET` ]] 
then exit;
fi

# rest of script goes here
```

the `-n` returns true if the string `cat /tmp/TESTRET` is NOT NULL indicating an error message were produced. and the `[ ]` is an alternate syntax for `test`.

**NOTE**: I experimented evaluating the value of GSERVER_STATUS with no consistent luck.

Also -- I've used the backticks here, but `$(cat /tmp/TESTRET)` would also work in this situation.

If you want to see the error produced, you can insert a `cat` into the `if` block:

```
if [[ -n $(cat /tmp/TESTRET) ]]
then
    cat /tmp/TESTRET;
    exit;
fi
```

And finally, if this script is called from within other scripts, the call to `exit` might not be want you want, so you can nest your additional code inside to avoid dropping out of the  script entirely:

```
if [[ -n $(cat /tmp/TESTRET) ]]
then
    cat /tmp/TESTRET;
else
    # rest of script goes here
    # ...
fi
```

or

```
if [[ -z $(cat /tmp/TESTRET) ]]
then
    # rest of script goes here
    # ...
else
    cat /tmp/TESTRET;
fi
```

Comment: BTW, a sidenote is that there appears to be a glitch in earlier versions of git with 'git ls-remote" where it inadvertantly returns this status. Once I switched to the latest version of git, the problem went away. However, it makes sense to adjust my Bash script with your suggestion because you never know when I could get any kind of error and need to not proceed further in the script when that happens.